# Restoring old DataRow and setting original version values?

Tags: datatable, dataset

I need to clone an entire datarow current/original values, for backup purposes.
If I use:

```
 private static DataRow CopyRow(DataRow dr)
         {
             DataRow drCopy = dr.Table.NewRow();
             DataRow drCopyOrig = dr.Table.NewRow();
             for (int i = 0; i < dr.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
             {
                 drCopy[i] = dr[i];
                 drCopyOrig[i] = dr[i,DataRowVersion.Original];
             }
             return drCopy;
         }
```

When restoring, my original values (dr["col",DataRowVersion.Original]) are lost, because I cannot set values to this expression.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to call [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges.aspx) on your DataSet or DataTable before accessing a DataRow's DataRowVersion property.

Excerpted from [Row States and Row Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0.aspx):

> When AcceptChanges is called on a DataSet, DataTable , or DataRow, all
>   rows with a row state of Deleted are removed. The remaining rows are
>   given a row state of Unchanged, and the values in the Original row
>   version are overwritten with the Current row version values. When
>   RejectChanges is called, all rows with a row state of Added are
>   removed. The remaining rows are given a row state of Unchanged, and
>   the values in the Current row version are overwritten with the
>   Original row version values.